# How can i get NodeId from FireBase Database in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("Your FireBase Database URL");
var result = await firebaseClient.Child("Node").OnceAsync<RelatedModel>();
```

How Can i get that NodeId (Same as Image) using this code?
[image: Firebase Database]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the `id` try the following:

```
FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("https://node.firebaseio.com/");
var result = await firebaseClient.Child("UsersInfo").OrderByKey().OnceAsync<RelatedModel>();

foreach (var res in results)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{res.Key}");
}
```

First get an instance of your firebase database, then add a reference to node `UsersInfo`. Then using `foreach` you iterate inside `results` and retrieve the `id` using `res.Key`